# Placing blocks on everything in Adventure mode

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

What is the command to give an item that can be placed on every block in Adventure mode in Minecraft 1.14.4?

This works for single blocks:

```
/give @p stone{CanPlaceOn:["stone","dirt"]}
```

But is there a simpler way than listing every single block?

Comment: Hi Dante, Im not a minecraft commands expert, but in general, questions like this will be more well received if you can show us what you have already tried. Just asking the community to write the command for you usually results in no answers and negative votes on the question. Do some research, try a few commands, and if you still cant get it, come back with what you have tried.

Comment: i did it myself, see answer

Comment: I edited your question, I hope you're OK with how it's worded now.

Comment: And now I've also added an example command to make the problem clearer. I want to see if I can get a question with score of -3 to a score of +3. :D

Comment: Please see [What to do before asking a minecraft-commands question?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13507/4797)

Answer (score 1):

You indeed have to do this with all blocks, not even [block tags](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tag#Block_tags) ([archive](https://minecraft.wiki/w/index.php?title=Tag&oldid=1457977#Block_tags)) work. You could try to do some complex workaround, like activating raytracing by some other action, setting a block, copying NBT to it and then taking one item from the player's inventory, but you would need to consider so many edge cases that it's not worth it.

Converting the list of all blocks into an extremely long `/give` command is easier (with automation) and luckily I've done this before for the `CanBreak` tag: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/350801/171580
This can easily be modified for `CanPlaceOn`:

```
/give @p minecraft:stone{CanPlaceOn:["acacia_button","acacia_door","acacia_fence_gate","acacia_fence","acacia_leaves","acacia_log","acacia_planks","acacia_pressure_plate","acacia_sapling","acacia_sign","acacia_slab","acacia_stairs","acacia_trapdoor","acacia_wall_sign","acacia_wood","activator_rail","allium","andesite","andesite_slab","andesite_stairs","andesite_wall","anvil","attached_melon_stem","attached_pumpkin_stem","azure_bluet","bamboo","bamboo_sapling","barrel","barrier","beacon","bedrock","beetroots","bell","birch_button","birch_door","birch_fence_gate","birch_fence","birch_leaves","birch_log","birch_planks","birch_pressure_plate","birch_sapling","birch_sign","birch_slab","birch_stairs","birch_trapdoor","birch_wall_sign","birch_wood","black_banner","black_bed","black_carpet","black_concrete_powder","black_concrete","black_glazed_terracotta","black_shulker_box","black_stained_glass","black_stained_glass_pane","black_terracotta","black_wall_banner","black_wool","blast_furnace","blue_banner","blue_bed","blue_carpet","blue_concrete_powder","blue_concrete","blue_glazed_terracotta","blue_ice","blue_orchid","blue_shulker_box","blue_stained_glass","blue_stained_glass_pane","blue_terracotta","blue_wall_banner","blue_wool","bone_block","bookshelf","brain_coral","brain_coral_block","brain_coral_fan","brain_coral_wall_fan","brewing_stand","brick_slab","brick_stairs","brick_wall","bricks","brown_banner","brown_bed","brown_carpet","brown_concrete_powder","brown_concrete","brown_glazed_terracotta","brown_mushroom_block","brown_mushroom","brown_shulker_box","brown_stained_glass","brown_stained_glass_pane","brown_terracotta","brown_wall_banner","brown_wool","bubble_column","bubble_coral","bubble_coral_block","bubble_coral_fan","bubble_coral_wall_fan","cactus","cake","campfire","carrots","cartography_table","carved_pumpkin","cauldron","chain_command_block","chest","chipped_anvil","chiseled_quartz_block","chiseled_red_sandstone","chiseled_sandstone","chiseled_stone_bricks","chorus_flower","chorus_plant","clay","coal_block","coal_ore","coarse_dirt","cobblestone","cobblestone_slab","cobblestone_stairs","cobblestone_wall","cobweb","cocoa","command_block","comparator","composter","conduit","cornflower","cracked_stone_bricks","crafting_table","creeper_head","creeper_wall_head","cut_red_sandstone","cut_red_sandstone_slab","cut_sandstone","cut_sandstone_slab","cyan_banner","cyan_bed","cyan_carpet","cyan_concrete_powder","cyan_concrete","cyan_glazed_terracotta","cyan_shulker_box","cyan_stained_glass","cyan_stained_glass_pane","cyan_terracotta","cyan_wall_banner","cyan_wool","damaged_anvil","dandelion","dark_oak_button","dark_oak_door","dark_oak_fence_gate","dark_oak_fence","dark_oak_leaves","dark_oak_log","dark_oak_planks","dark_oak_pressure_plate","dark_oak_sapling","dark_oak_sign","dark_oak_slab","dark_oak_stairs","dark_oak_trapdoor","dark_oak_wall_sign","dark_oak_wood","dark_prismarine","dark_prismarine_slab","dark_prismarine_stairs","daylight_detector","dead_brain_coral","dead_brain_coral_block","dead_brain_coral_fan","dead_brain_coral_wall_fan","dead_bubble_coral","dead_bubble_coral_block","dead_bubble_coral_fan","dead_bubble_coral_wall_fan","dead_bush","dead_fire_coral","dead_fire_coral_block","dead_fire_coral_fan","dead_fire_coral_wall_fan","dead_horn_coral","dead_horn_coral_block","dead_horn_coral_fan","dead_horn_coral_wall_fan","dead_tube_coral","dead_tube_coral_block","dead_tube_coral_fan","dead_tube_coral_wall_fan","detector_rail","diamond_block","diamond_ore","diorite","diorite_slab","diorite_stairs","diorite_wall","dirt","dispenser","dragon_egg","dragon_head","dragon_wall_head","dried_kelp_block","dropper","emerald_block","emerald_ore","enchanting_table","end_gateway","end_portal_frame","end_portal","end_rod","end_stone","end_stone_brick_slab","end_stone_brick_stairs","end_stone_brick_wall","end_stone_bricks","ender_chest","farmland","fern","fire","fire_coral","fire_coral_block","fire_coral_fan","fire_coral_wall_fan","fletching_table","flower_pot","frosted_ice","furnace","glass","glass_pane","glowstone","gold_block","gold_ore","granite","granite_slab","granite_stairs","granite_wall","grass_block","grass_path","grass","gravel","gray_banner","gray_bed","gray_carpet","gray_concrete_powder","gray_concrete","gray_glazed_terracotta","gray_shulker_box","gray_stained_glass","gray_stained_glass_pane","gray_terracotta","gray_wall_banner","gray_wool","green_banner","green_bed","green_carpet","green_concrete_powder","green_concrete","green_glazed_terracotta","green_shulker_box","green_stained_glass","green_stained_glass_pane","green_terracotta","green_wall_banner","green_wool","grindstone","hay_block","heavy_weighted_pressure_plate","hopper","horn_coral","horn_coral_block","horn_coral_fan","horn_coral_wall_fan","ice","infested_chiseled_stone_bricks","infested_cobblestone","infested_cracked_stone_bricks","infested_mossy_stone_bricks","infested_stone","infested_stone_bricks","iron_bars","iron_door","iron_block","iron_ore","iron_trapdoor","jack_o_lantern","jigsaw","jukebox","jungle_button","jungle_door","jungle_fence_gate","jungle_fence","jungle_leaves","jungle_log","jungle_planks","jungle_pressure_plate","jungle_sapling","jungle_sign","jungle_slab","jungle_stairs","jungle_trapdoor","jungle_wall_sign","jungle_wood","kelp","kelp_plant","ladder","lantern","lapis_block","lapis_ore","large_fern","lectern","lever","light_blue_banner","light_blue_bed","light_blue_carpet","light_blue_concrete_powder","light_blue_concrete","light_blue_glazed_terracotta","light_blue_shulker_box","light_blue_stained_glass","light_blue_stained_glass_pane","light_blue_terracotta","light_blue_wall_banner","light_blue_wool","light_gray_banner","light_gray_bed","light_gray_carpet","light_gray_concrete_powder","light_gray_concrete","light_gray_glazed_terracotta","light_gray_shulker_box","light_gray_stained_glass","light_gray_stained_glass_pane","light_gray_terracotta","light_gray_wall_banner","light_gray_wool","light_weighted_pressure_plate","lilac","lily_pad","lily_of_the_valley","lime_banner","lime_bed","lime_carpet","lime_concrete_powder","lime_concrete","lime_glazed_terracotta","lime_shulker_box","lime_stained_glass","lime_stained_glass_pane","lime_terracotta","lime_wall_banner","lime_wool","loom","magenta_banner","magenta_bed","magenta_carpet","magenta_concrete_powder","magenta_concrete","magenta_glazed_terracotta","magenta_shulker_box","magenta_stained_glass","magenta_stained_glass_pane","magenta_terracotta","magenta_wall_banner","magenta_wool","magma_block","melon","melon_stem","mossy_cobblestone","mossy_cobblestone_slab","mossy_cobblestone_stairs","mossy_cobblestone_wall","mossy_stone_brick_slab","mossy_stone_brick_stairs","mossy_stone_brick_wall","mossy_stone_bricks","moving_piston","mushroom_stem","mycelium","nether_brick_fence","nether_brick_slab","nether_brick_stairs","nether_brick_wall","nether_bricks","nether_portal","nether_quartz_ore","nether_wart_block","nether_wart","netherrack","note_block","oak_button","oak_door","oak_fence_gate","oak_fence","oak_leaves","oak_log","oak_planks","oak_pressure_plate","oak_sapling","oak_sign","oak_slab","oak_stairs","oak_trapdoor","oak_wall_sign","oak_wood","observer","obsidian","orange_banner","orange_bed","orange_carpet","orange_concrete_powder","orange_concrete","orange_glazed_terracotta","orange_shulker_box","orange_stained_glass","orange_stained_glass_pane","orange_terracotta","orange_tulip","orange_wall_banner","orange_wool","oxeye_daisy","packed_ice","peony","petrified_oak_slab","pink_banner","pink_bed","pink_carpet","pink_concrete_powder","pink_concrete","pink_glazed_terracotta","pink_shulker_box","pink_stained_glass","pink_stained_glass_pane","pink_terracotta","pink_tulip","pink_wall_banner","pink_wool","piston_head","piston","player_head","player_wall_head","podzol","polished_andesite","polished_andesite_slab","polished_andesite_stairs","polished_diorite","polished_diorite_slab","polished_diorite_stairs","polished_granite","polished_granite_slab","polished_granite_stairs","poppy","potatoes","potted_acacia_sapling","potted_allium","potted_azure_bluet","potted_bamboo","potted_birch_sapling","potted_blue_orchid","potted_brown_mushroom","potted_cactus","potted_cornflower","potted_dandelion","potted_dark_oak_sapling","potted_dead_bush","potted_fern","potted_jungle_sapling","potted_lily_of_the_valley","potted_oak_sapling","potted_orange_tulip","potted_oxeye_daisy","potted_pink_tulip","potted_poppy","potted_red_mushroom","potted_red_tulip","potted_spruce_sapling","potted_white_tulip","potted_wither_rose","powered_rail","prismarine","prismarine_brick_slab","prismarine_brick_stairs","prismarine_bricks","prismarine_slab","prismarine_stairs","prismarine_wall","pumpkin","pumpkin_stem","purple_banner","purple_bed","purple_carpet","purple_concrete_powder","purple_concrete","purple_glazed_terracotta","purple_shulker_box","purple_stained_glass","purple_stained_glass_pane","purple_terracotta","purple_wall_banner","purple_wool","purpur_block","purpur_pillar","purpur_slab","purpur_stairs","quartz_block","quartz_pillar","quartz_slab","quartz_stairs","rail","red_banner","red_bed","red_carpet","red_concrete_powder","red_concrete","red_glazed_terracotta","red_mushroom_block","red_mushroom","red_nether_brick_slab","red_nether_brick_stairs","red_nether_brick_wall","red_nether_bricks","red_sand","red_sandstone","red_sandstone_slab","red_sandstone_stairs","red_sandstone_wall","red_shulker_box","red_stained_glass","red_stained_glass_pane","red_terracotta","red_tulip","red_wall_banner","red_wool","redstone_block","redstone_lamp","redstone_ore","redstone_torch","redstone_wall_torch","redstone_wire","repeater","repeating_command_block","rose_bush","sand","sandstone","sandstone_slab","sandstone_stairs","sandstone_wall","scaffolding","sea_lantern","sea_pickle","seagrass","shulker_box","skeleton_skull","skeleton_wall_skull","slime_block","smithing_table","smoker","smooth_quartz","smooth_quartz_slab","smooth_quartz_stairs","smooth_red_sandstone","smooth_red_sandstone_slab","smooth_red_sandstone_stairs","smooth_sandstone","smooth_sandstone_slab","smooth_sandstone_stairs","smooth_stone","smooth_stone_slab","snow_block","snow","soul_sand","spawner","sponge","spruce_button","spruce_door","spruce_fence_gate","spruce_fence","spruce_leaves","spruce_log","spruce_planks","spruce_pressure_plate","spruce_sapling","spruce_sign","spruce_slab","spruce_stairs","spruce_trapdoor","spruce_wall_sign","spruce_wood","sticky_piston","stone","stone_brick_slab","stone_brick_stairs","stone_brick_wall","stone_bricks","stone_button","stone_pressure_plate","stone_slab","stone_stairs","stonecutter","stripped_acacia_log","stripped_acacia_wood","stripped_birch_log","stripped_birch_wood","stripped_dark_oak_log","stripped_dark_oak_wood","stripped_jungle_log","stripped_jungle_wood","stripped_oak_log","stripped_oak_wood","stripped_spruce_log","stripped_spruce_wood","structure_block","structure_void","sugar_cane","sunflower","sweet_berry_bush","tnt","tall_grass","tall_seagrass","terracotta","torch","trapped_chest","tripwire_hook","tripwire","tube_coral","tube_coral_block","tube_coral_fan","tube_coral_wall_fan","turtle_egg","vine","wall_torch","water","wet_sponge","wheat","white_banner","white_bed","white_carpet","white_concrete_powder","white_concrete","white_glazed_terracotta","white_shulker_box","white_stained_glass","white_stained_glass_pane","white_terracotta","white_tulip","white_wall_banner","white_wool","wither_rose","wither_skeleton_skull","wither_skeleton_wall_skull","yellow_banner","yellow_bed","yellow_carpet","yellow_concrete_powder","yellow_concrete","yellow_glazed_terracotta","yellow_shulker_box","yellow_stained_glass","yellow_stained_glass_pane","yellow_terracotta","yellow_wall_banner","yellow_wool","zombie_head","zombie_wall_head"]}
```

This works for Minecraft 1.14.4.

Comment: Note you have to put this in a command block and can’t in chat

Answer (score 1):

In 1.16.4 (at least--this is where I am) there seem to be more general categories like `#minecraft:base_stone_overworld` and `#minecraft:walls` and `#minecraft:slabs` (note the leading hashtag) which might make this easier.

Answer (score -2):

nvd I did it myself

```
give @a minecraft:oak_log{CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:acacia_button",
"minecraft:acacia_door",
"minecraft:acacia_fence",
"minecraft:acacia_fence_gate",
"minecraft:acacia_leaves",
"minecraft:acacia_log",
"minecraft:acacia_planks",
"minecraft:acacia_pressure_plate",
"minecraft:acacia_sapling",
"minecraft:acacia_sign",
"minecraft:acacia_slab",
"minecraft:acacia_stairs",
"minecraft:acacia_trapdoor",
"minecraft:acacia_wall_sign",
"minecraft:acacia_wood",
"minecraft:activator_rail",
"minecraft:air",
"minecraft:allium",
"minecraft:andesite",
"minecraft:andesite_slab",
"minecraft:andesite_stairs",
"minecraft:andesite_wall",
"minecraft:anvil",
"minecraft:attached_melon_stem",
"minecraft:attached_pumpkin_stem",
"minecraft:azure_bluet",
"minecraft:bamboo",
"minecraft:bamboo_sapling",
"minecraft:barrel",
"minecraft:barrier",
"minecraft:beacon",
"minecraft:bedrock",
"minecraft:beetroots",
"minecraft:bell",
"minecraft:birch_button",
"minecraft:birch_door",
"minecraft:birch_fence",
"minecraft:birch_fence_gate",
"minecraft:birch_leaves",
"minecraft:birch_log",
"minecraft:birch_planks",
"minecraft:birch_pressure_plate",
"minecraft:birch_sapling",
"minecraft:birch_sign",
"minecraft:birch_slab",
"minecraft:birch_stairs",
"minecraft:birch_trapdoor",
"minecraft:birch_wall_sign",
"minecraft:birch_wood",
"minecraft:black_banner",
"minecraft:black_bed",
"minecraft:black_carpet",
"minecraft:black_concrete",
"minecraft:black_concrete_powder",
"minecraft:black_glazed_terracotta",
"minecraft:black_shulker_box",
"minecraft:black_stained_glass",
"minecraft:black_stained_glass_pane",
"minecraft:black_terracotta",
"minecraft:black_wall_banner",
"minecraft:black_wool",
"minecraft:blast_furnace",
"minecraft:blue_banner",
"minecraft:blue_bed",
"minecraft:blue_carpet",
"minecraft:blue_concrete",
"minecraft:blue_concrete_powder",
"minecraft:blue_glazed_terracotta",
"minecraft:blue_ice",
"minecraft:blue_orchid",
"minecraft:blue_shulker_box",
"minecraft:blue_stained_glass",
"minecraft:blue_stained_glass_pane",
"minecraft:blue_terracotta",
"minecraft:blue_wall_banner",
"minecraft:blue_wool",
"minecraft:bone_block",
"minecraft:bookshelf",
"minecraft:brain_coral",
"minecraft:brain_coral_block",
"minecraft:brain_coral_fan",
"minecraft:brain_coral_wall_fan",
"minecraft:brewing_stand",
"minecraft:brick_slab",
"minecraft:brick_stairs",
"minecraft:brick_wall",
"minecraft:bricks",
"minecraft:brown_banner",
"minecraft:brown_bed",
"minecraft:brown_carpet",
"minecraft:brown_concrete",
"minecraft:brown_concrete_powder",
"minecraft:brown_glazed_terracotta",
"minecraft:brown_mushroom",
"minecraft:brown_mushroom_block",
"minecraft:brown_shulker_box",
"minecraft:brown_stained_glass",
"minecraft:brown_stained_glass_pane",
"minecraft:brown_terracotta",
"minecraft:brown_wall_banner",
"minecraft:brown_wool",
"minecraft:bubble_column",
"minecraft:bubble_coral",
"minecraft:bubble_coral_block",
"minecraft:bubble_coral_fan",
"minecraft:bubble_coral_wall_fan",
"minecraft:cactus",
"minecraft:cake",
"minecraft:campfire",
"minecraft:carrots",
"minecraft:cartography_table",
"minecraft:carved_pumpkin",
"minecraft:cauldron",
"minecraft:cave_air",
"minecraft:chain_command_block",
"minecraft:chest",
"minecraft:chipped_anvil",
"minecraft:chiseled_quartz_block",
"minecraft:chiseled_red_sandstone",
"minecraft:chiseled_sandstone",
"minecraft:chiseled_stone_bricks",
"minecraft:chorus_flower",
"minecraft:chorus_plant",
"minecraft:clay",
"minecraft:coal_block",
"minecraft:coal_ore",
"minecraft:coarse_dirt",
"minecraft:cobblestone",
"minecraft:cobblestone_slab",
"minecraft:cobblestone_stairs",
"minecraft:cobblestone_wall",
"minecraft:cobweb",
"minecraft:cocoa",
"minecraft:command_block",
"minecraft:comparator",
"minecraft:composter",
"minecraft:conduit",
"minecraft:cornflower",
"minecraft:cracked_stone_bricks",
"minecraft:crafting_table",
"minecraft:creeper_head",
"minecraft:creeper_wall_head",
"minecraft:cut_red_sandstone",
"minecraft:cut_red_sandstone_slab",
"minecraft:cut_sandstone",
"minecraft:cut_sandstone_slab",
"minecraft:cyan_banner",
"minecraft:cyan_bed",
"minecraft:cyan_carpet",
"minecraft:cyan_concrete",
"minecraft:cyan_concrete_powder",
"minecraft:cyan_glazed_terracotta",
"minecraft:cyan_shulker_box",
"minecraft:cyan_stained_glass",
"minecraft:cyan_stained_glass_pane",
"minecraft:cyan_terracotta",
"minecraft:cyan_wall_banner",
"minecraft:cyan_wool",
"minecraft:damaged_anvil",
"minecraft:dandelion",
"minecraft:dark_oak_button",
"minecraft:dark_oak_door",
"minecraft:dark_oak_fence",
"minecraft:dark_oak_fence_gate",
"minecraft:dark_oak_leaves",
"minecraft:dark_oak_log",
"minecraft:dark_oak_planks",
"minecraft:dark_oak_pressure_plate",
"minecraft:dark_oak_sapling",
"minecraft:dark_oak_sign",
"minecraft:dark_oak_slab",
"minecraft:dark_oak_stairs",
"minecraft:dark_oak_trapdoor",
"minecraft:dark_oak_wall_sign",
"minecraft:dark_oak_wood",
"minecraft:dark_prismarine",
"minecraft:dark_prismarine_slab",
"minecraft:dark_prismarine_stairs",
"minecraft:daylight_detector",
"minecraft:dead_brain_coral",
"minecraft:dead_brain_coral_block",
"minecraft:dead_brain_coral_fan",
"minecraft:dead_brain_coral_wall_fan",
"minecraft:dead_bubble_coral",
"minecraft:dead_bubble_coral_block",
"minecraft:dead_bubble_coral_fan",
"minecraft:dead_bubble_coral_wall_fan",
"minecraft:dead_bush",
"minecraft:dead_fire_coral",
"minecraft:dead_fire_coral_block",
"minecraft:dead_fire_coral_fan",
"minecraft:dead_fire_coral_wall_fan",
"minecraft:dead_horn_coral",
"minecraft:dead_horn_coral_block",
"minecraft:dead_horn_coral_fan",
"minecraft:dead_horn_coral_wall_fan",
"minecraft:dead_tube_coral",
"minecraft:dead_tube_coral_block",
"minecraft:dead_tube_coral_fan",
"minecraft:dead_tube_coral_wall_fan",
"minecraft:detector_rail",
"minecraft:diamond_block",
"minecraft:diamond_ore",
"minecraft:diorite",
"minecraft:diorite_slab",
"minecraft:diorite_stairs",
"minecraft:diorite_wall",
"minecraft:dirt",
"minecraft:dispenser",
"minecraft:dragon_egg",
"minecraft:dragon_head",
"minecraft:dragon_wall_head",
"minecraft:dried_kelp_block",
"minecraft:dropper",
"minecraft:emerald_block",
"minecraft:emerald_ore",
"minecraft:enchanting_table",
"minecraft:end_gateway",
"minecraft:end_portal",
"minecraft:end_portal_frame",
"minecraft:end_rod",
"minecraft:end_stone",
"minecraft:end_stone_brick_slab",
"minecraft:end_stone_brick_stairs",
"minecraft:end_stone_brick_wall",
"minecraft:end_stone_bricks",
"minecraft:ender_chest",
"minecraft:farmland",
"minecraft:fern",
"minecraft:fire",
"minecraft:fire_coral",
"minecraft:fire_coral_block",
"minecraft:fire_coral_fan",
"minecraft:fire_coral_wall_fan",
"minecraft:fletching_table",
"minecraft:flower_pot",
"minecraft:frosted_ice",
"minecraft:furnace",
"minecraft:glass",
"minecraft:glass_pane",
"minecraft:glowstone",
"minecraft:gold_block",
"minecraft:gold_ore",
"minecraft:granite",
"minecraft:granite_slab",
"minecraft:granite_stairs",
"minecraft:granite_wall",
"minecraft:grass",
"minecraft:grass_block",
"minecraft:grass_path",
"minecraft:gravel",
"minecraft:gray_banner",
"minecraft:gray_bed",
"minecraft:gray_carpet",
"minecraft:gray_concrete",
"minecraft:gray_concrete_powder",
"minecraft:gray_glazed_terracotta",
"minecraft:gray_shulker_box",
"minecraft:gray_stained_glass",
"minecraft:gray_stained_glass_pane",
"minecraft:gray_terracotta",
"minecraft:gray_wall_banner",
"minecraft:gray_wool",
"minecraft:green_banner",
"minecraft:green_bed",
"minecraft:green_carpet",
"minecraft:green_concrete",
"minecraft:green_concrete_powder",
"minecraft:green_glazed_terracotta",
"minecraft:green_shulker_box",
"minecraft:green_stained_glass",
"minecraft:green_stained_glass_pane",
"minecraft:green_terracotta",
"minecraft:green_wall_banner",
"minecraft:green_wool",
"minecraft:grindstone",
"minecraft:hay_block",
"minecraft:heavy_weighted_pressure_plate",
"minecraft:hopper",
"minecraft:horn_coral",
"minecraft:horn_coral_block",
"minecraft:horn_coral_fan",
"minecraft:horn_coral_wall_fan",
"minecraft:ice",
"minecraft:infested_chiseled_stone_bricks",
"minecraft:infested_cobblestone",
"minecraft:infested_cracked_stone_bricks",
"minecraft:infested_mossy_stone_bricks",
"minecraft:infested_stone",
"minecraft:infested_stone_bricks",
"minecraft:iron_bars",
"minecraft:iron_block",
"minecraft:iron_door",
"minecraft:iron_ore",
"minecraft:iron_trapdoor",
"minecraft:jack_o_lantern",
"minecraft:jigsaw",
"minecraft:jukebox",
"minecraft:jungle_button",
"minecraft:jungle_door",
"minecraft:jungle_fence",
"minecraft:jungle_fence_gate",
"minecraft:jungle_leaves",
"minecraft:jungle_log",
"minecraft:jungle_planks",
"minecraft:jungle_pressure_plate",
"minecraft:jungle_sapling",
"minecraft:jungle_sign",
"minecraft:jungle_slab",
"minecraft:jungle_stairs",
"minecraft:jungle_trapdoor",
"minecraft:jungle_wall_sign",
"minecraft:jungle_wood",
"minecraft:kelp",
"minecraft:kelp_plant",
"minecraft:ladder",
"minecraft:lantern",
"minecraft:lapis_block",
"minecraft:lapis_ore",
"minecraft:large_fern",
"minecraft:lava",
"minecraft:lectern",
"minecraft:lever",
"minecraft:light_blue_banner",
"minecraft:light_blue_bed",
"minecraft:light_blue_carpet",
"minecraft:light_blue_concrete",
"minecraft:light_blue_concrete_powder",
"minecraft:light_blue_glazed_terracotta",
"minecraft:light_blue_shulker_box",
"minecraft:light_blue_stained_glass",
"minecraft:light_blue_stained_glass_pane",
"minecraft:light_blue_terracotta",
"minecraft:light_blue_wall_banner",
"minecraft:light_blue_wool",
"minecraft:light_gray_banner",
"minecraft:light_gray_bed",
"minecraft:light_gray_carpet",
"minecraft:light_gray_concrete",
"minecraft:light_gray_concrete_powder",
"minecraft:light_gray_glazed_terracotta",
"minecraft:light_gray_shulker_box",
"minecraft:light_gray_stained_glass",
"minecraft:light_gray_stained_glass_pane",
"minecraft:light_gray_terracotta",
"minecraft:light_gray_wall_banner",
"minecraft:light_gray_wool",
"minecraft:light_weighted_pressure_plate",
"minecraft:lilac",
"minecraft:lily_of_the_valley",
"minecraft:lily_pad",
"minecraft:lime_banner",
"minecraft:lime_bed",
"minecraft:lime_carpet",
"minecraft:lime_concrete",
"minecraft:lime_concrete_powder",
"minecraft:lime_glazed_terracotta",
"minecraft:lime_shulker_box",
"minecraft:lime_stained_glass",
"minecraft:lime_stained_glass_pane",
"minecraft:lime_terracotta",
"minecraft:lime_wall_banner",
"minecraft:lime_wool",
"minecraft:loom",
"minecraft:magenta_banner",
"minecraft:magenta_bed",
"minecraft:magenta_carpet",
"minecraft:magenta_concrete",
"minecraft:magenta_concrete_powder",
"minecraft:magenta_glazed_terracotta",
"minecraft:magenta_shulker_box",
"minecraft:magenta_stained_glass",
"minecraft:magenta_stained_glass_pane",
"minecraft:magenta_terracotta",
"minecraft:magenta_wall_banner",
"minecraft:magenta_wool",
"minecraft:magma_block",
"minecraft:melon",
"minecraft:melon_stem",
"minecraft:mossy_cobblestone",
"minecraft:mossy_cobblestone_slab",
"minecraft:mossy_cobblestone_stairs",
"minecraft:mossy_cobblestone_wall",
"minecraft:mossy_stone_brick_slab",
"minecraft:mossy_stone_brick_stairs",
"minecraft:mossy_stone_brick_wall",
"minecraft:mossy_stone_bricks",
"minecraft:moving_piston",
"minecraft:mushroom_stem",
"minecraft:mycelium",
"minecraft:nether_brick_fence",
"minecraft:nether_brick_slab",
"minecraft:nether_brick_stairs",
"minecraft:nether_brick_wall",
"minecraft:nether_bricks",
"minecraft:nether_portal",
"minecraft:nether_quartz_ore",
"minecraft:nether_wart",
"minecraft:nether_wart_block",
"minecraft:netherrack",
"minecraft:note_block",
"minecraft:oak_button",
"minecraft:oak_door",
"minecraft:oak_fence",
"minecraft:oak_fence_gate",
"minecraft:oak_leaves",
"minecraft:oak_log",
"minecraft:oak_planks",
"minecraft:oak_pressure_plate",
"minecraft:oak_sapling",
"minecraft:oak_sign",
"minecraft:oak_slab",
"minecraft:oak_stairs",
"minecraft:oak_trapdoor",
"minecraft:oak_wall_sign",
"minecraft:oak_wood",
"minecraft:observer",
"minecraft:obsidian",
"minecraft:orange_banner",
"minecraft:orange_bed",
"minecraft:orange_carpet",
"minecraft:orange_concrete",
"minecraft:orange_concrete_powder",
"minecraft:orange_glazed_terracotta",
"minecraft:orange_shulker_box",
"minecraft:orange_stained_glass",
"minecraft:orange_stained_glass_pane",
"minecraft:orange_terracotta",
"minecraft:orange_tulip",
"minecraft:orange_wall_banner",
"minecraft:orange_wool",
"minecraft:oxeye_daisy",
"minecraft:packed_ice",
"minecraft:peony",
"minecraft:petrified_oak_slab",
"minecraft:pink_banner",
"minecraft:pink_bed",
"minecraft:pink_carpet",
"minecraft:pink_concrete",
"minecraft:pink_concrete_powder",
"minecraft:pink_glazed_terracotta",
"minecraft:pink_shulker_box",
"minecraft:pink_stained_glass",
"minecraft:pink_stained_glass_pane",
"minecraft:pink_terracotta",
"minecraft:pink_tulip",
"minecraft:pink_wall_banner",
"minecraft:pink_wool",
"minecraft:piston",
"minecraft:piston_head",
"minecraft:player_head",
"minecraft:player_wall_head",
"minecraft:podzol",
"minecraft:polished_andesite",
"minecraft:polished_andesite_slab",
"minecraft:polished_andesite_stairs",
"minecraft:polished_diorite",
"minecraft:polished_diorite_slab",
"minecraft:polished_diorite_stairs",
"minecraft:polished_granite",
"minecraft:polished_granite_slab",
"minecraft:polished_granite_stairs",
"minecraft:poppy",
"minecraft:potatoes",
"minecraft:potted_acacia_sapling",
"minecraft:potted_allium",
"minecraft:potted_azure_bluet",
"minecraft:potted_bamboo",
"minecraft:potted_birch_sapling",
"minecraft:potted_blue_orchid",
"minecraft:potted_brown_mushroom",
"minecraft:potted_cactus",
"minecraft:potted_cornflower",
"minecraft:potted_dandelion",
"minecraft:potted_dark_oak_sapling",
"minecraft:potted_dead_bush",
"minecraft:potted_fern",
"minecraft:potted_jungle_sapling",
"minecraft:potted_lily_of_the_valley",
"minecraft:potted_oak_sapling",
"minecraft:potted_orange_tulip",
"minecraft:potted_oxeye_daisy",
"minecraft:potted_pink_tulip",
"minecraft:potted_poppy",
"minecraft:potted_red_mushroom",
"minecraft:potted_red_tulip",
"minecraft:potted_spruce_sapling",
"minecraft:potted_white_tulip",
"minecraft:potted_wither_rose",
"minecraft:powered_rail",
"minecraft:prismarine",
"minecraft:prismarine_brick_slab",
"minecraft:prismarine_brick_stairs",
"minecraft:prismarine_bricks",
"minecraft:prismarine_slab",
"minecraft:prismarine_stairs",
"minecraft:prismarine_wall",
"minecraft:pumpkin",
"minecraft:pumpkin_stem",
"minecraft:purple_banner",
"minecraft:purple_bed",
"minecraft:purple_carpet",
"minecraft:purple_concrete",
"minecraft:purple_concrete_powder",
"minecraft:purple_glazed_terracotta",
"minecraft:purple_shulker_box",
"minecraft:purple_stained_glass",
"minecraft:purple_stained_glass_pane",
"minecraft:purple_terracotta",
"minecraft:purple_wall_banner",
"minecraft:purple_wool",
"minecraft:purpur_block",
"minecraft:purpur_pillar",
"minecraft:purpur_slab",
"minecraft:purpur_stairs",
"minecraft:quartz_block",
"minecraft:quartz_pillar",
"minecraft:quartz_slab",
"minecraft:quartz_stairs",
"minecraft:rail",
"minecraft:red_banner",
"minecraft:red_bed",
"minecraft:red_carpet",
"minecraft:red_concrete",
"minecraft:red_concrete_powder",
"minecraft:red_glazed_terracotta",
"minecraft:red_mushroom",
"minecraft:red_mushroom_block",
"minecraft:red_nether_brick_slab",
"minecraft:red_nether_brick_stairs",
"minecraft:red_nether_brick_wall",
"minecraft:red_nether_bricks",
"minecraft:red_sand",
"minecraft:red_sandstone",
"minecraft:red_sandstone_slab",
"minecraft:red_sandstone_stairs",
"minecraft:red_sandstone_wall",
"minecraft:red_shulker_box",
"minecraft:red_stained_glass",
"minecraft:red_stained_glass_pane",
"minecraft:red_terracotta",
"minecraft:red_tulip",
"minecraft:red_wall_banner",
"minecraft:red_wool",
"minecraft:redstone_block",
"minecraft:redstone_lamp",
"minecraft:redstone_ore",
"minecraft:redstone_torch",
"minecraft:redstone_wall_torch",
"minecraft:redstone_wire",
"minecraft:repeater",
"minecraft:repeating_command_block",
"minecraft:rose_bush",
"minecraft:sand",
"minecraft:sandstone",
"minecraft:sandstone_slab",
"minecraft:sandstone_stairs",
"minecraft:sandstone_wall",
"minecraft:scaffolding",
"minecraft:sea_lantern",
"minecraft:sea_pickle",
"minecraft:seagrass",
"minecraft:shulker_box",
"minecraft:skeleton_skull",
"minecraft:skeleton_wall_skull",
"minecraft:slime_block",
"minecraft:smithing_table",
"minecraft:smoker",
"minecraft:smooth_quartz",
"minecraft:smooth_quartz_slab",
"minecraft:smooth_quartz_stairs",
"minecraft:smooth_red_sandstone",
"minecraft:smooth_red_sandstone_slab",
"minecraft:smooth_red_sandstone_stairs",
"minecraft:smooth_sandstone",
"minecraft:smooth_sandstone_slab",
"minecraft:smooth_sandstone_stairs",
"minecraft:smooth_stone",
"minecraft:smooth_stone_slab",
"minecraft:snow",
"minecraft:snow_block",
"minecraft:soul_sand",
"minecraft:spawner",
"minecraft:sponge",
"minecraft:spruce_button",
"minecraft:spruce_door",
"minecraft:spruce_fence",
"minecraft:spruce_fence_gate",
"minecraft:spruce_leaves",
"minecraft:spruce_log",
"minecraft:spruce_planks",
"minecraft:spruce_pressure_plate",
"minecraft:spruce_sapling",
"minecraft:spruce_sign",
"minecraft:spruce_slab",
"minecraft:spruce_stairs",
"minecraft:spruce_trapdoor",
"minecraft:spruce_wall_sign",
"minecraft:spruce_wood",
"minecraft:sticky_piston",
"minecraft:stone",
"minecraft:stone_brick_slab",
"minecraft:stone_brick_stairs",
"minecraft:stone_brick_wall",
"minecraft:stone_bricks",
"minecraft:stone_button",
"minecraft:stone_pressure_plate",
"minecraft:stone_slab",
"minecraft:stone_stairs",
"minecraft:stonecutter",
"minecraft:stripped_acacia_log",
"minecraft:stripped_acacia_wood",
"minecraft:stripped_birch_log",
"minecraft:stripped_birch_wood",
"minecraft:stripped_dark_oak_log",
"minecraft:stripped_dark_oak_wood",
"minecraft:stripped_jungle_log",
"minecraft:stripped_jungle_wood",
"minecraft:stripped_oak_log",
"minecraft:stripped_oak_wood",
"minecraft:stripped_spruce_log",
"minecraft:stripped_spruce_wood",
"minecraft:structure_block",
"minecraft:structure_void",
"minecraft:sugar_cane",
"minecraft:sunflower",
"minecraft:sweet_berry_bush",
"minecraft:tall_grass",
"minecraft:tall_seagrass",
"minecraft:terracotta",
"minecraft:tnt",
"minecraft:torch",
"minecraft:trapped_chest",
"minecraft:tripwire",
"minecraft:tripwire_hook",
"minecraft:tube_coral",
"minecraft:tube_coral_block",
"minecraft:tube_coral_fan",
"minecraft:tube_coral_wall_fan",
"minecraft:turtle_egg",
"minecraft:vine",
"minecraft:void_air",
"minecraft:wall_torch",
"minecraft:water",
"minecraft:wet_sponge",
"minecraft:wheat",
"minecraft:white_banner",
"minecraft:white_bed",
"minecraft:white_carpet",
"minecraft:white_concrete",
"minecraft:white_concrete_powder",
"minecraft:white_glazed_terracotta",
"minecraft:white_shulker_box",
"minecraft:white_stained_glass",
"minecraft:white_stained_glass_pane",
"minecraft:white_terracotta",
"minecraft:white_tulip",
"minecraft:white_wall_banner",
"minecraft:white_wool",
"minecraft:wither_rose",
"minecraft:wither_skeleton_skull",
"minecraft:wither_skeleton_wall_skull",
"minecraft:yellow_banner",
"minecraft:yellow_bed",
"minecraft:yellow_carpet",
"minecraft:yellow_concrete",
"minecraft:yellow_concrete_powder",
"minecraft:yellow_glazed_terracotta",
"minecraft:yellow_shulker_box",
"minecraft:yellow_stained_glass",
"minecraft:yellow_stained_glass_pane",
"minecraft:yellow_terracotta",
"minecraft:yellow_wall_banner",
"minecraft:yellow_wool",
"minecraft:zombie_head",
"minecraft:zombie_wall_head",
],HideFlags:16}
```

Comment: I hope you didn't type all of that manually, because I've done almost the same before (automated): https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/350801/171580

Comment: yeah i did it with google doc find and replace

Comment: But from what source?